# columnconfigure and rowconfigure not clearing when creating new frame

Tags: tkinter, frame, destroy

I have created 2 different screens that I can switch between using menu buttons. The first screen opens as expected regardless of the screen that I choose as the tk.Frame to pass to the 'switch_frame' method. The problem that I am requesting assistance with is that that when I switch to the other frame it looks like the grid configuration is not being cleared even though I am using 'grid_forget' and 'destroy'. Then when I switch back to the initial screen it is not the same as it was before hence why I think it is something to do with the grid_rowconfigure and grid_columnconfigure methods.

```
import tkinter as tk

app_size = "800x600"

class NewController(tk.Tk):#child of tkinter class

    def __init__ (self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Controller')
        self.frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Screen2)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class): #function to allow switching between screens

        global screen_flag

        if self.frame is not None: #check if there is an existing frame existing
            self.frame.destroy() #remove existing frame/close window

        new_frame = frame_class(self) #create new frame of passed tk frame and self being the tk.TK
        self.frame = new_frame
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw',)
        self.focus_force()

class Screen1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.colour = 'white'
        self.configure(bg = self.colour)
        master.geometry(app_size)
        #master.grid_forget()
        master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)# Configure main root frame so that it can resize
        master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)# Configure main root frame so that it can resize
        master.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=5)# Configure main root frame so that it can resize

        #Configure Frame 1
        self.menu_top = tk.Frame(master)#create frame 1
        self.menu_top.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) #locate frame 1 on root grid
        for x in range(5):
            self.menu_top.grid_columnconfigure(x, weight=1)     
        self.menu_top.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Configure Frame 2
        self.bottom_area = tk.Frame(master, bg="#fffaaa") #create frame 2 
        self.bottom_area.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) #locate frame 2 on root grid
        for x in range(3):
            self.bottom_area.grid_columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
        self.bottom_area.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.widgets(master)

    def widgets(self, master):
        # Create widgets
        #Configure the grid in the menu_top Frame
        menu_button1 = tk.Button(self.menu_top, text="Menu 1", command= lambda: self.closeframes(master, Screen1))
        menu_button2 = tk.Button(self.menu_top, text="Menu 2", command= lambda: self.closeframes(master, Screen2))
        menu_button3 = tk.Button(self.menu_top, text="Menu 3", command=self.buttonpress)
        menu_button4 = tk.Button(self.menu_top, text="Menu 4", command=self.buttonpress)
        menu_button5 = tk.Button(self.menu_top, text="Menu 5", command=self.buttonpress)

        menu_button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        menu_button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) 
        menu_button3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        menu_button4.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        menu_button5.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)

        #Configure the grid in the bottom_area Frame
        menu_button1 = tk.Button(self.bottom_area, text="Menu 1", command=self.buttonpress)
        menu_button2 = tk.Button(self.bottom_area, text="Menu 2", command=self.buttonpress)
        menu_button3 = tk.Button(self.bottom_area, text="Menu 3", command=self.buttonpress)

        menu_button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        menu_button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) 
        menu_button3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)

    #function used to get and set all information from entry fields at once
    def closeframes(self, master, next_screen):
        self.menu_top.grid_forget()
        self.bottom_area.grid_forget()
        list = master.grid_slaves()
        for l in list:
            l.destroy()
        master.switch_frame(next_screen)

    def buttonpress(self):
        print ("click!")

class Screen2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.colour = 'white'
        self.configure(bg = self.colour)
        master.geometry(app_size)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)# Configure main root frame so that it can resize
        master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)# Configure main root frame so that it can resize
        master.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)# Configure main root frame so that it can resize

        #Configure Frame 1
        self.left_area = tk.Frame(master)#create frame 1
        self.left_area.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) #locate frame 1 on root grid
        for x in range(5):
            self.left_area.grid_rowconfigure(x, weight=1)       
        self.left_area.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Configure Frame 2
        self.right_area = tk.Frame(master, bg="#fffaaa") #create frame 2 
        self.right_area.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) #locate frame 2 on root grid
        for x in range(3):
            self.right_area.grid_rowconfigure(x, weight=1)
        self.right_area.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.widgets(master)

    def widgets(self, master):      
        # Create widgets
        #Configure the grid in the left_area Frame
        left_button1 = tk.Button(self.left_area, text="left 1", command=lambda: self.closeframes(master, Screen1))
        left_button2 = tk.Button(self.left_area, text="left 2", command=lambda: self.closeframes(master, Screen2))
        left_button3 = tk.Button(self.left_area, text="left 3", command=self.buttonpress)
        left_button4 = tk.Button(self.left_area, text="left 4", command=self.buttonpress)
        left_button5 = tk.Button(self.left_area, text="left 5", command=self.buttonpress)

        left_button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        left_button2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) 
        left_button3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        left_button4.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        left_button5.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)


        #Configure the grid in the right_area Frame
        right_button1 = tk.Button(self.right_area, text="right 1", command=self.buttonpress)
        right_button2 = tk.Button(self.right_area, text="right 2", command=self.buttonpress)
        right_button3 = tk.Button(self.right_area, text="right 3", command=self.buttonpress)

        right_button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        right_button2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) 
        right_button3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)

    def buttonpress(self):
        print ("click!")

    def closeframes(self, master, next_screen):
        master.frame.grid_forget()
        self.right_area.grid_forget()
        self.left_area.grid_forget()
        list = master.grid_slaves()
        for l in list:
            l.destroy()
        master.frame.destroy()

        master.switch_frame(next_screen)

Controller = NewController()
Controller.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***`#self.frame.pack(...`***: You have commented the layout statement, so how do you expect the `Frame` to be displayed?

Comment: True, I have edited by adding 'self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw',)' in replace of the pack. The configure problem still exists.

Comment: ***configure problem still exists***: Yes, you are using a `Frame` in `Frame` layout where you layout outside the current `Frame` using `tk.Frame(master)`. Do you really want to layout this `Frame` into the `master` Frame?

Comment: yes, I am trying to put multiple frames inside a frame. Its the only way I achieve putting different grid layouts on the same screen with the limited Python/TKinter knowledge that I have. I have tried to provide a simplified version of a larger program that I am working on which has graphs, buttons, labels arranged differently on each screen.

Comment: ***yes, I am trying to put multiple frames inside a frame***: This don't answer my question, please respond to my question. Strip also down your example to **one** widget per `Frame` and use different background colours per `Frame` to see which `Frame` is displaced.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments @stovfl made no sense to me at first but after using your suggestion to change colours of the frames and also the tk window I finally understand what you were talking about.. I think..

I changed the location of where the subframes were laid out, from master(tk.TK window) to self(tk.Frame).

I also put the row and column configure on the tk window so that each of the screen frames would fill the tk window.

I hope this code helps others.

```
import Tkinter as tk

app_size = "800x600"

class NewController(tk.Tk):

    def __init__ (self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Controller')
        self.frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Screen2)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class): #function to allow switching between screens

        if self.frame is not None: #check if there is an existing frame existing
            self.frame.destroy() #remove existing frame/close window
        self.geometry(app_size)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame = frame_class(self) #create new frame of passed tk frame and self being the tk.TK
        self.focus_force()

class Screen1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.config(bg="green", borderwidth=10, relief="sunken")
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Configure Frame 1
        self.menu_top = tk.Frame(self, bg="blue")#create frame 1
        self.menu_top.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) #locate frame 1 on master frame
        for x in range(5):
            self.menu_top.grid_columnconfigure(x, weight=1)     
        self.menu_top.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Configure Frame 2
        self.bottom_area = tk.Frame(self, bg="pink") #create frame 2 
        self.bottom_area.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) #locate frame 2 master frame
        for x in range(3):
            self.bottom_area.grid_columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
        self.bottom_area.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.widgets(master)

    def widgets(self, master):
        # Create widgets
        #Configure the grid in the menu_top Frame
        menu_button1 = tk.Button(self.menu_top, text="Menu 1", command= lambda: master.switch_frame(Screen1))
        menu_button2 = tk.Button(self.menu_top, text="Menu 2", command= lambda: master.switch_frame(Screen2))
        menu_button3 = tk.Button(self.menu_top, text="Menu 3", command=self.buttonpress)
        menu_button4 = tk.Button(self.menu_top, text="Menu 4", command=self.buttonpress)
        menu_button5 = tk.Button(self.menu_top, text="Menu 5", command=self.buttonpress)
        menu_button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        menu_button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) 
        menu_button3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        menu_button4.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        menu_button5.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)

        #Configure the grid in the bottom_area Frame
        menu_button1 = tk.Button(self.bottom_area, text="Menu 1", command=self.buttonpress)
        menu_button2 = tk.Button(self.bottom_area, text="Menu 2", command=self.buttonpress)
        menu_button3 = tk.Button(self.bottom_area, text="Menu 3", command=self.buttonpress)
        menu_button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        menu_button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) 
        menu_button3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)

    def buttonpress(self):
        print ("click!")

class Screen2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.config(bg="green", borderwidth=10, relief="sunken")
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        #Configure Frame 1
        self.left_area = tk.Frame(self, bg="red", borderwidth=5)#create frame 1
        self.left_area.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) #locate frame 1 on root grid
        for x in range(5):
            self.left_area.grid_rowconfigure(x, weight=1)       
        self.left_area.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Configure Frame 2
        self.right_area = tk.Frame(self, bg="yellow", borderwidth=5) #create frame 2 
        self.right_area.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) #locate frame 2 on root grid
        for x in range(3):
            self.right_area.grid_rowconfigure(x, weight=1)
        self.right_area.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.widgets(master)

    def widgets(self, master):      
        # Create widgets
        #Configure the grid in the left_area Frame
        left_button1 = tk.Button(self.left_area, text="left 1", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Screen1))
        left_button2 = tk.Button(self.left_area, text="left 2", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Screen2))
        left_button3 = tk.Button(self.left_area, text="left 3", command=self.buttonpress)
        left_button4 = tk.Button(self.left_area, text="left 4", command=self.buttonpress)
        left_button5 = tk.Button(self.left_area, text="left 5", command=self.buttonpress)
        left_button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        left_button2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) 
        left_button3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        left_button4.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        left_button5.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)

        #Configure the grid in the right_area Frame
        right_button1 = tk.Button(self.right_area, text="right 1", command=self.buttonpress)
        right_button2 = tk.Button(self.right_area, text="right 2", command=self.buttonpress)
        right_button3 = tk.Button(self.right_area, text="right 3", command=self.buttonpress)
        right_button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)
        right_button2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1) 
        right_button3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nesw', padx=1, pady=1)

    def buttonpress(self):
        print ("click!")

Controller = NewController()

Controller.mainloop()
```